# how to find the area of the shaded region inside the square?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

[image]

if each side is $ 10m $ then what is the area of the shade region ? I tried this $$4\times\int_5^{5\sqrt3}dx\int_5^{5\sqrt3}\sqrt{100-y^2}dy$$ but i did not get the right answer. what more I have to do, help me. Thank you

Comment: There should be a duplicate lying somewhere...

Comment: are those curves made by circles of radius 10 and centers at the corners?

Comment: yes #jacob classen

Answer (score 2):

Hint. It should be
$$4\cdot
\int_5^{5\sqrt3}dx\int_5^{\sqrt{100-x^2}}dy=4\cdot
\int_5^{5\sqrt3}\left(\sqrt{100-x^2}-5\right)dx,$$
that is four time the area between the graphs of the functions  $f(x)=\sqrt{100-x^2}$ and $g(x)=5$ over the interval $[5,5\sqrt3]$.
The result should be multiplied by $m^2$.